# Leer Archivo con Scanner

Tags: java, archivo, scanner

tengo leer un archivo de un autómata y decir si la cadena es valida o no, cuando ingreso datos manualmente funciona bien, pero cuando lo lee desde el archivo solo el primer dato me lo da correcto, y los demás no los toma en cuenta.
Por ejemplo:
babb - es una cadena valida
aaba - no es valida
babb - es valida, pero me dice que no es valida

```
File f = new File("C:/Users/Arale/Documents/Hola.txt");

        try{
   Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);



   entrada = new Scanner(f);

     while(entrada.hasNextLine()){

       app.cadena = entrada.nextLine();

       System.out.println(app.cadena);

int valor = app.estado_A();
        if (valor == app.aceptado) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cadena Valida");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cadena invalida");
        }


}//fin de while
    //entrada.close();

}catch(FileNotFoundException e){

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El archivo no existe...");
}
```

Comment: Hay unas cosas que están comentadas por que estaba probando

Comment: Aquí hay dos partes, el leer la cadena del fichero y evaluar si la cadena es válida... ¿cuál es la que te está dando problemas?

Comment: La de evaluar que la cadena sea valida =(

Comment: ¿Puedes subir el código de `app`? Necesitamos ver qué hace `app.estado_A()`. También necesitamos ver qué devuelve `app.aceptado`. En general, necesitamos ver el código del objeto `app` o la clase desde donde instancias dicho objeto.